# Read and Modify the key value in XML using Bash/Shell script

Tags: xml, bash

I need to read (store in variable) and then change the online_hostname key value in XML using bash/shell script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bzinfo>
    <myidentity online_hostname="testdevice-air_2022_01_25" 
                bzlogin="me@abc.com" />
</bzinfo>
```

I am able to read the value but not able to change it.

```
cat test.xml | grep '<myidentity ' | sed -E 's/.*online_hostname="?([^ "]*)"? .*/\1/'
```

Comment: Obligatory [parsing XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1032785)

Answer (score 1):

[Please DO NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) [use `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [to parse/edit XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)! Use an XML-parser instead.

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  x:replace-nodes(//@online_hostname,function($x){attribute {name($x)} {"newhost"}})
' --output-format=xml --output-node-indent
```

With [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//@online_hostname' -v 'newhost' input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing in the environment variable

```
MYVAR="newhost"
```

It could be solved like this

```
sed -rie 's@online_hostname="(.*?) (.*)"@online_hostname="'$MYVAR'" \2@' test.xml
```

the first group of regular expression matches lazy to " in other words, first appearance of ".
The second group (.*) meaning anything, is preserved in \2,
using @ as separator -i as in-place of and r as extended regular expressions.

Comment: I am getting the below error when trying sed. "sed: 1: "test.xml": undefined label 'est.xml' ". Also I need the value of  online_hostname  in a variable. Thanks.

Comment: Also <myidentity online_hostname="michael-g’s-macbook-air_2022_04_18" bzlogin="it@socure.com" /> is a one liner. This command removes the bzlogin="it@socure.com part. Thanks.

Comment: sed: 1: "s@online_hostname="(.*? ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid -  I tried the new command, got this error. I am on trying on macOS. Is that specific I am missing? Thanks